# how can I connect to a remote mongo server from Mac OS terminal

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I would like to drop into the mongo shell in the terminal on my MacBook.  However, I'm interested in connecting to a Mongo instance that is running in the cloud (compose.io instance via Heroku addon).  I have the name, password, host, port, and database name from the MongoDB URI:

```
mongodb://username:password@somewhere.mongolayer.com:10011/my_database
```

I have installed mongodb on my MacBook using Homebrew not because I want Mongo running on my Mac, but just to get access to the mongo shell program in order to connect to this remote database.

However, I can't find the right command to get me the full shell access I would like.  Using instructions found here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/ (search for "remote") I am able to get what looks like a connection, but without giving my username or password I am not fully connected.  Running `db.auth(username, password)` returns 1 (as opposed to "auth fails" when I provide incorrect username and password), but I continue to get an "unauthorized" error message when issuing the `show dbs` command.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

You are probably connecting fine but don't have sufficient privileges to run `show dbs`.

You don't need to run the db.auth if you pass the auth in the command line:

```
mongo somewhere.mongolayer.com:10011/my_database -u username -p password
```

Once you connect are you able to see collections?

```
> show collections
```

If so all is well and you just don't have admin privileges to the database and can't run the `show dbs`

Comment: I am able to connect using the technique you describe.  However, I can't run any commands, such as "show collections" or "show users".  I keen getting a "not authorized for query on my_db.system.namespaces" error.

Comment: Ok, so heroku randomly named my mongo database a different name from the one I've been using in dev.  I think that was basically my issue.

Comment: But if i have ?authSource=admin in the end. It doesn't work.
--authenticationDatabase doesn't help.

Comment: 27017 is the default port though. just in case the example port doesn't work.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/

Answer (score 69):

With Mongo [3.2 and higher](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6233) just use your connection string as is:

```
mongo mongodb://username:password@somewhere.mongolayer.com:10011/my_database
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is:

```
mongo mongodb://mongoDbIPorDomain:port
```