# How to enable authentication on MongoDB through Docker?

Tags: mongodb, docker

I want to spin-up a docker for `mongodb:latest` but allow only certain user(s) to access certain db(s) (i.e. enable `--auth`). No one else should access mongodb whatsoever! How should I do this as part of the docker initiation?

BTW, `data directory` sits on the host by utilising the following command during initiation: `-v /my/own/datadir:/data/db`.

Answer (score 147):

If you take a look at:

- https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/4.2/Dockerfile
- https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/4.2/docker-entrypoint.sh#L303-L313

you will notice that there are two variables used in the `docker-entrypoint.sh`:

- **MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME**
- **MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD**

You can use them to setup root user. For example you can use following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
mongo-container:
  image: mongo:3.4.2
  environment:
      # provide your credentials here
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootPassXXX
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  volumes:
      # if you wish to setup additional user accounts specific per DB or with different roles you can use following entry point
    - "$PWD/mongo-entrypoint/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/"
  # no --auth is needed here as presence of username and password add this option automatically
  command: mongod
```

Now when starting the container by `docker-compose up` you should notice following entries:

```
...
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, processManagement: { fork: true }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "/proc/1/fd/1" } }
...
I ACCESS   [conn1] note: no users configured in admin.system.users, allowing localhost access
...
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "root",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

To add custom users apart of root use the entrypoint exectuable script (placed under $PWD/mongo-entrypoint dir as it is mounted in `docker-compose` to entrypoint):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Creating mongo users..."
mongo admin --host localhost -u USER_PREVIOUSLY_DEFINED -p PASS_YOU_PREVIOUSLY_DEFINED --eval "db.createUser({user: 'ANOTHER_USER', pwd: 'PASS', roles: [{role: 'readWrite', db: 'xxx'}]}); db.createUser({user: 'admin', pwd: 'PASS', roles: [{role: 'userAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'admin'}]});"
echo "Mongo users created."
```

Entrypoint script will be executed and additional users will be created.

Comment: I switched to using the username and password environment variables (as you demonstrated in your answer) so that my mongo instance could start in authenticated mode automatically. Prior, I had to start it unsecured, create my users with a docker-entrypoint .js script, and then restart the instance in authenticated mode. When I try to use your bash script to create a new user (in a new db -- not admin), I get an Authentication failed error. I tried running directly in my running mongo container, and I still get the same error. Any reason that you can think of for this?

Comment: If you have users created in the database other then admin you probably need to provide additional option `--authenticationDatabase` to tell server where to look for the user you are authenticating with.
You can verify if authentication works in 2 ways:
- connect from shell with `mongo DB --host -u USER -p PASS --authenticationDatabase DB`
- or connect via localhost mode: `mongo --host localhost` and then `use YOUR_DB` followed by `db.auth("USER","PASS")`

Comment: Thanks, I was previously unaware of the --authenticationDatabase directive. That did the trick.

Comment: The env vars will not create a user on an already created database, but they do ensure mongod is started with --auth since you need it even after the first start ... `docker-compose` tries really hard to preserve your data volumes between container recreations ... If there is nothing important in there you can always `docker-compose rm -fv <servicename>` and try again ... Still no luck? If you've mounted a shared volume to preserve the data then you'll have to empty that out. https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/174#issuecomment-297538188

Comment: https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/329#issuecomment-460858099

Comment: it shows the user is created but still i get UserNotFound: Could not find user "" for ""

Comment: Sept. 21 update: nothing in this page works with mongo:latest (5.0). Had to downgrade to 3.6.23. Also, the documentation says to specify strings, not arrays. So no `- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root`, but rather `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root`

Comment: what will be the MongoDB URL for connecting it to my application ? I tried `mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost:27017/admin` but it didn't work

Answer (score 70):

**a. You can use environment variables via terminal:**

```
$ docker run -d --name container_name \
      -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin \
      -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \
      mongo
```

If you like to test if everything works:

```
// ssh into the running container
// Change container name if necessary
$ docker exec -it mongo /bin/bash

// Enter into mongo shell
$ mongo

// Caret will change when you enter successfully
// Switch to admin database
$> use admin
$> db.auth("admin", passwordPrompt())

// Show available databases
$> show dbs
```

If you like to instantiate a database on first run, check option b.

**b. You can use environment variables in your docker stack deploy file or compose file for versions 3.4 through 4.1.**

As it is explained on the quick reference section of the [official mongo image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) set `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` in your yaml file:

```
mongo:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

[docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh) file in mongo image checks for the existence of these two variables and sets `--auth` flag accordingly.

**c. You can also use docker secrets.**

`MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` is set indirectly by docker-entrypoint.sh from `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME_FILE` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE` variables:

```
mongo:
    image: mongo
    environment:
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME_FILE=/run/secrets/db_root_username
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/db_root_password
    secrets:
      - db_root_username
      - db_root_password
```

docker-entrypoint.sh converts `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME_FILE` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE` to `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD`.

You can use `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` in your `.sh` or `.js` scripts in `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder while initializing database instance.

When a container is started for the first time it will execute files with extensions `.sh` and `.js` that are found in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. `.js` files will be executed by mongo using the database specified by the `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` variable, if it is present, or test otherwise. You may also switch databases within the `.js` script.

This last method is not in the reference docs, so it may not survive an update.

Comment: I tried option b, and I'm still able to connect to mongo remotely without any authentication - I mean just by typing `mongo ip:port`

Comment: @sbk Once there was a bug in mongodb in that nature but as far as I know it got fixed. It must be something to do with your settings. Make sure you have the right settings and try restarting.

Comment: What if I initially started mongo container without user, password?  How do I restart container with --auth enable?

Comment: heads up, after 6.0 its mongosh not mongo

Comment: @DucksEatTurtles Mongosh is a repl environment. > "The MongoDB Shell is a standalone product, it’s developed separately from the MongoDB Server and it’s open-source under the Apache 2 license."

Answer (score 44):

I have hard time when trying to

- Create other db than **admin**
- Add new users and enable authentication to the db above

So I made **2021** answer here

My directory looks like this

```
├── docker-compose.yml
└── mongo-entrypoint
    └── entrypoint.js
```

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  mongo-container:
    # If you need to connect to your db from outside this container 
    network_mode: host
    image: mongo:4.2
    environment:
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - "$PWD/mongo-entrypoint/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/"
    command: mongod
```

Please change `admin` and `pass` with your need.

Inside `mongo-entrypoint`, I have `entrypoint.js` file with this content:

```
var db = connect("mongodb://admin:pass@localhost:27017/admin");

db = db.getSiblingDB('new_db'); // we can not use "use" statement here to switch db

db.createUser(
    {
        user: "user",
        pwd: "pass",
        roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "new_db"} ],
        passwordDigestor: "server",
    }
)
```

Here again you need to change `admin:pass` to your root mongo credentials in your `docker-compose.yml` that you stated before. In additional you need to change `new_db`, `user`, `pass` to your new database name and credentials that you need.

Now you can:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

And connect to this db from localhost, please note that I already have mongo cli, you can install it or you can exec to the container above to use `mongo` command:

```
mongo new_db -u user -p pass
```

Or you can connect from other computer

```
mongo host:27017/new_db -u user -p pass
```

My git repository:
https://github.com/sexydevops/docker-compose-mongo

Hope it can help someone, I lost my afternoon for this ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for writing this out. this was exactly what i needed. one change i needed was that `$PWD` must be replaced with `.` Note, the admin username must be different than the username you want to create for the new database

Comment: BTW there is `db = new Mongo().getDB("myDatabase");` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Mongo.getDB/

Comment: How can you guys make these configurations work, with a hyphen-space before your line? like this `- `, whereas I receive this: `services.mongo.environment.0 must be a string` if I do. The official doco says to just write parameter names as string, not as arrays (i.e. starting with hyphen space).

Comment: Thank you, In fact the script was not needed, i only had to specify the -u username -p password parameters to docker exec -it my_container mongosh to have acces to the database, since these are already specified in docker file as ENV parameters. But still the script is nice though, with it I can initialise the db

Answer (score 37):

> Better solutions for furthering:
>   https://blog.madisonhub.org/setting-up-a-mongodb-server-with-auth-on-docker/
>   https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/tutorial/add-user-administrator/

Here's what I did for the same problem, and it worked.

1. Run the mongo docker instance on your server

   ```
   docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v ~/dataMongo:/data/db mongo
   ```
2. Open bash on the running docker instance.

   ```
   docker ps
   ```

   > CONTAINER IDIMAGE   COMMAND  CREATED STATUS  PORTS  NAMES
   >
   > b07599e429fb   mongo   "docker-entrypoint..."   35 minutes ago  Up 35 minutes   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   musing_stallman

   ```
   docker exec -it b07599e429fb bash
   root@b07599e429fb:/#
   ```

   Reference- https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up-legacy/wiki/Accessing-the-running-Mongodb-docker-container-from-command-line-on-EC2
3. Enter the mongo shell by typing mongo.

   ```
   root@b07599e429fb:/# mongo
   ```
4. For this example, I will set up a user named ian and give that user read & write access to the cool_db database.

   ```
   > use cool_db

   > db.createUser({
       user: 'ian',
       pwd: 'secretPassword',
       roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db:'cool_db'}]
   })
   ```

   Reference: https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/mongodb-auth/ (First point only)
5. Exit from mongod shell and bash.
6. Stop the docker instance using the below command.

   ```
   docker stop mongo
   ```
7. Now run the mongo docker with auth enabled.

   ```
   docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v ~/dataMongo:/data/db mongo mongod --auth
   ```

   Reference: [How to enable authentication on MongoDB through Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559557/how-to-enable-authentication-on-mongodb-through-docker/34562109#34562109) (Usman Ismail's answer to this question)
8. I was able to connect to the instance running on a Google Cloud server from my local windows laptop using the below command.

   ```
   mongo <ip>:27017/cool_db -u ian -p secretPassword
   ```

   Reference: [how can I connect to a remote mongo server from Mac OS terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813912/how-can-i-connect-to-a-remote-mongo-server-from-mac-os-terminal/26814077#26814077)

Comment: How `docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v ~/dataMongo:/data/db mongo` this command start unsecured mongo db,? Which help us to add initial commands.

Comment: Hi thanks for this answer, but I'm stuck on step 6. How can you `run` given that you already have a container for MongoDB? You have to kill the container that allows you to setup auth, and then rerun it with auth? I don't get it.

Comment: @Eric Yes you have to stop the running docker instance before running the 'run' command again. I have updated the answer with this info. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Ankur, Yes, the command starts unsecured mongo, through which you can add security.

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me a login failed, as now I have 2 different containers: one with an user but auth not set, and one with auth set but no user, so I can't connect. I guess that's the `-v ~/dataMonogo/data/db` that I don't get, I not familiar with devops/hosting

Comment: @EricBurel Probably too late for you, but you were right, the `-v` takes care to save the db with the new user outside the container, so we are able to relink the same data in the new container. However, you missed the colon in your quote, it's actually `~/dataMongo:/data/db`. Maybe that's the reason why you did not see the user in your new container.

Comment: On Step 7...  You are not restarting your exisitng container you created in step 1 are you?  You baiscally create a new container mapping the volumn to the same location as 1st container, correct?

Comment: 2 heads up.

1. use mongosh instead of mongo to get repl
2. use this method to create a root user in admin db to get a common user for all dbs.

db.createUser ( { user: "<username>", pwd: "<password>", roles: [ "root"] })

Answer (score 14):

Just dropping a .js file into the entry point init folder works for this

e.g. entrypoint.js

```
var db = connect("mongodb://localhost/admin");

db.createUser(
    {
        user: "yourAdminUserName",
        pwd: "yourAdminPassword",
        roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
    }
)
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
db:
  image: mongo:3.2
  volumes:
   - /my/own/datadir:/data/db
   - ../mongo-entrypoint:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Doing the rest by hand or more of the same works.

If you want to you can also drop a .sh file into the init folder to clean up the files so they are not laying around: zz-cleanup.sh.

Answer (score 9):

The Dockerfile for the official mongo image is [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/982328582c74dd2f0a9c8c77b84006f291f974c3/2.2/Dockerfile). The default command is mongod but you can override to add the --auth switch assuming user's are already configured.

```
docker run -d .... mongodb:latest mongod --auth
```

If the user has to be created then you need to volume mount a startup script into `/entrypoint.sh` to replace the default startup script and then have that script create users and start mongo with the auth switch.

```
docker run -d .... -v $PWD/my_custom_script.sh:/entrypoint.sh mongodb:latest
```

Comment: when i try to mount the script as a volume, i get an error "not a directory"

Comment: I think docker only supports mount directory instead of file.

Answer (score 7):

I want to comment but don't have enough reputation.

The user-adding executable script shown above has to be modified with 
**--authenticationDatabase admin** and **NEWDATABASENAME**.

```
mongo --authenticationDatabase admin --host localhost -u USER_PREVIOUSLY_DEFINED -p PASS_YOU_PREVIOUSLY_DEFINED NEWDATABASENAME --eval "db.createUser({user: 'NEWUSERNAME', pwd: 'PASSWORD', roles: [{role: 'readWrite', db: 'NEWDATABASENAME'}]});"
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdyXo.png

Comment: MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE variable can be used to set the database name (e.g. NEWDATABASENAME) for scripts under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. The default value is `test`.

Answer (score 6):

@jbochniak: Thanks, although at first read I thought I've already discovered all of this, it turned out that your example (esp. the version of the Mongo Docker image) helped me out!

That version (v3.4.2) and the v3.4 (currently corresponding to v3.4.3) still support 'MONGO_INITDB_ROOT' specified through those variables, **as of v3.5 (at least tags '3' and 'latest') DON'T work as described** in your answer and in the docs.

I quickly had a look at the code on GitHub, but saw similar usage of these variables and couldn't find the bug immediately, should do so before filing this as a bug...

Comment: Thanks for the warning, double checked the source for `3.5` and it has them now too: https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/3.5/docker-entrypoint.sh#L117-L118

Answer (score 6):

use this images to fix:

With docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  db:
    image: aashreys/mongo-auth:latest
    environment:
      - AUTH=yes
      - MONGODB_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - MONGODB_ADMIN_PASS=admin123
      - MONGODB_APPLICATION_DATABASE=sample
      - MONGODB_APPLICATION_USER=aashrey
      - MONGODB_APPLICATION_PASS=admin123
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
     // more configuration
```

- [aashreys/mongo-auth - Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/aashreys/mongo-auth/)
- [aashreys/docker-mongo-auth: Easily setup authentication on Docker's Official MongoDB image.](https://github.com/aashreys/docker-mongo-auth)

Comment: This creates a "test" database as well. How can we prevent that?

Comment: test maybe a default database, you can drop it.- [MongoDB Drop Database](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_drop_database.htm)

Comment: as per the docker mongo docs, it says that : "When a container is started for the first time it will execute files with extensions .sh and .js that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. .js files will be executed by mongo using the database specified by the MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE variable, if it is present, or test otherwise."
So once you are in the database, you should be able to drop the db.

Answer (score 5):

you can use env variables to setup username and password for mongo

```
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

using simple docker command

```
docker run -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=my-user MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-password mongo
```

using docker-compose

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: my-user
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: my-password
```

and the last option is to manually access the container and set the user and password inside the mongo docker container

```
docker exec -it mongo-container bash
```

now you can use mongo shell command to configure everything that you want

Answer (score 5):

Pretend you have two containers one for mongodb and one for api service, for mongo container to have user when initiating in addition to username & password you must add **MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE** too.

```
version: '3.4'

services:   

    mymongo:
        container_name: mymongo
        environment:
          - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin // This is important
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=YOURPASSWORD
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
           - "27017:27017"
        volumes:
           - mongo-database:/data/db     
    
    post.api:
        container_name: post.api
        environment:
          - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
          - DatabaseSettings__ConnectionString=mongodb://root:YOURPASSWORD@mymongodb:27017
        ports:
          - "5010:80" 

volumes:
  mongo-database:
    external: false
```

And in your api service(here is post.api) in `ApplicationContext.cs` would be like this :

```
public ApplicationContext(IDatabaseSettings settings)
        {
            _settings = settings ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(settings));

            MongoClient client = new(settings.ConnectionString);            
            IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);    
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

It works for me.

Create container with DB name

```
docker run -d \
--name mongodb \
-e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=trackdb \
-p 27017:27017 \
mongo
```

Go to in container and create user

```
docker exec -it mongodb bash
mongo
use trackdb
db.createUser({user: "user", pwd: "secretPassword",roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db:'trackdb'}]})
exit
exit
```

Stop container:

```
docker stop mongodb
```

Check your container ID via:

```
docker ps -a
```

Change docker configuration (with your favorite editor)

```
sudo nano /var/lib/docker/containers/<YOUR_CONTAINER_ID>/config.v2.json
```

Find 2 places and add second argument:

`"Args":["mongod"],` --> `"Args":["mongod","--auth"],`

`"Cmd":["mongod"],` --> `"Cmd":["mongod","--auth"],`

Should be enough just restart the docker service, but I did `sudo reboot now`.

After the reboot you can verify your changes: `docker inspect mongodb` and find 2nd argument in 2 places.
Start container and check authentication.

Enjoy!