# can't login to mongoDB in a docker-compose container with login/pass

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

On my distant server, I use a docker container started with:

`MONBULDING_PORT="8080" docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build monbulding-mongo`

It works pretty well if I don't set any username/password to authenticate.
Here is the corresponding `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```yaml
monbulding-mongo:
  image: mongo:latest
  ports:
   - "27017:27017"
```

Now, if I want to set a username/password to access to MongoDB, I change this file into:

```yaml
monbulding-mongo:
  image: mongo:latest
  ports:
   - "27017:27017"
  environment:
   - AUTH=yes
   - MONGODB_ADMIN_USER=admin
   - MONGODB_ADMIN_PASS=password
   - MONGODB_APPLICATION_DATABASE=app
   - MONGODB_APPLICATION_USER=user
   - MONGODB_APPLICATION_PASS=password
```

And if I try to log in to MongoDB using `Robo 3T`, it doesn't work:[image]

Someone know what I do wrong ?
Thanks!

**EDIT :**
I also tried with `mongo shell`:

`mongo --host domain.net -u admin -p password`

But there is an error too.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559557/how-to-enable-authentication-on-mongodb-through-docker

Comment: I already did... :/

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this: https://github.com/aashreys/docker-mongo-auth it creates a file `/data/db/.mongodb_password_set` after creating the user, so next time it skips the user creation. If you need to force it to create another user make sure to remove that file