# User not found on MongoDB Docker image with authentication

Tags: mongodb, docker

So I'm trying to setup a MongoDB using the official [mongo Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo), version `4.2`.

What I want to achieve is to use the server with authentication enabled, and I want to have a custom database with a custom user and password.

So, I'm setting the following environment variables:

```
MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: mydb
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: jane
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
```

In the documentation it states that if you provide the latter two environment variables, authentication is enabled automatically.

However, when I then try to access the `mydb` database using the credentials `jane` and `secret`, all I get is an error:

```
Supported SASL mechanisms requested for unknown user 'jane@mydb'
SASL SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for jane on mydb from client 172.17.0.1:54702 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user "jane" for db "mydb"
```

Why is that? What am I missing?

My guess is that the user created only has access to the `admin` database, and I need to grant access for the user `jane` to the database `mydb`. I tried to do that using the following command:

```
mongo admin -u jane -p secret --eval "db.grantRolesToUser('jane', [{role: 'dbOwner', db: 'mydb'}])"
```

But this didn't work either. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try from localhost...

Comment: Also this may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559557/how-to-enable-authentication-on-mongodb-through-docker

Comment: Yes, I run all of this from `localhost`.

Comment: `mongo admin -u jane -p 'secret'` worked for me

Comment: Including the `--eval` part?

Comment: yes I just place the password in single qoutes

Comment: posting docker-compose file as an answer so might help? let me know if it help. may be in your case it becuase of volume? so there might be user already exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can authenticate with **jane**,**secret** against **admin** db, not **mydb**

Running `mongo -u jane -p secret` is equivalent to running `mongo -u jane -p secret -authenticationDatabase admin`. Check container logs to verify it.

MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE is for different purpose.

As [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) state:

> MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME, MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD These
> variables, used in conjunction, create a new user and set that user's
> password. This user is created in the **admin authentication database**
> and given the role of root, which is a "superuser" role.
>
> MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE This variable allows you to specify the name of
> a database to be used for creation scripts in
> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.js (see Initializing a fresh instance
> below). MongoDB is fundamentally designed for "create on first use",
> so if you do not insert data with your JavaScript files, then no
> database is created.
>
> **Initializing a fresh** **instance** When a container is started for the first time it will execute files
> with extensions .sh and .js that are found in
> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
> order. .js files will be executed by mongo using the database
> specified by the MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE variable, if it is present, or
> test otherwise. You may also switch databases within the .js script.