# Mongodb authentication failed when try to create a collection

Tags: mongodb, docker

I tried to build a mongo db manually, here is the code to start the container

```
sudo docker run -d  --name mongodb1 -p 27017:27017 -v mongo_db:/data/db1 \
  -e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin \
  -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongoadmin \
  -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret mongo:latest
```

The container was created successfully, but there is no any default database such as admin.
When I tried to create a collection, I got below error message.
I checked the existing thread [How to enable authentication on MongoDB through Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559557/how-to-enable-authentication-on-mongodb-through-docker), but it did not help for my case.

```
> show dbs
> use customer
switched to db customer
> db.createCollection("customerList")
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "command create requires authentication",
        "code" : 13,
        "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After googling, I find the answer.
When try to access mongo db, need to mention user/pw with mongo

```
sudo docker exec -it mongodb1 /bin/bash
mongo -u mongoadmin -p secret
```