# fastify + mongo = why nothing is stored inside database?

Tags: mongodb, fastify

I am building a fastify application with mongodb. I've created this package.json file with a script to run mongo.

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@fastify/mongodb": "5.0.0",
        "fastify": "4.11.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node server.js",
        "start-mongo": "docker run -d --name my-mongo -p 27017:27017 mongo",
    }
}
```

And with `npm run start-mongo` I run mongo exposing port 27017. Then, ... this is fastify part.

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({logger: true})

fastify.register(require('@fastify/mongodb'), {
    forceClose: true,
    url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/library'
})

fastify.get('/books', async(request, reply) => {
    const books = await fastify.mongo.db
        .collection('books')
        .find()

    reply.send(books)
});

fastify.post('/books', async(request, reply) => {
    const result = await fastify
        .mongo.db
        .collection('books')
        .insertOne(request.body)

    reply.send({
        message: 'book added',
        id: result.insertId
    })
})
```

GET /books:

```
{"_events":{},"_eventsCount":0}
```

POST /books

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/books -d '{"message":"prova"}'
```

returns

```
{"message":"book added"}
```

It is strange because response should contain also id. But it doesnt.

```
    reply.send({
        message: 'book added',
        id: result.insertId
    })
```

This means that

```
    const result = await fastify
        .mongo.db
        .collection('books')
        .insertOne(request.body)
```

doesnt store the book. Any error is displayed and GET always return:

```
{"_events":{},"_eventsCount":0}
```

What's wrong?

--

I've also created mongo with docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

but it returns:

```
{
  statusCode: 500,
  code: '13',
  error: 'Internal Server Error',
  message: 'command insert requires authentication'
}
{
  statusCode: 500,
  code: '13',
  error: 'Internal Server Error',
  message: 'command find requires authentication'
}
```

I updated code from

```
fastify.register(require('@fastify/mongodb'), {
    forceClose: true,
    url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/library'
})
```

to

```
fastify.register(require('@fastify/mongodb'), {
    forceClose: true,
    url: 'mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017/library'
})
```

but returns:

```
(node:86146) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
    at Connection.onMessage (/Users/simonegentili/Development/github.com/sensorario/youtube.poliglotta/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:227:30)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/Users/simonegentili/Development/github.com/sensorario/youtube.poliglotta/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:60:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at processIncomingData (/Users/simonegentili/Development/github.com/sensorario/youtube.poliglotta/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:125:16)
    at MessageStream._write (/Users/simonegentili/Development/github.com/sensorario/youtube.poliglotta/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:33:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
    at Socket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:726:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:86146) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:86146) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Why "Authentication failed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. update [fastify mongo to v6](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-mongodb/releases/tag/v6.0.0) that supports fastify v4
2. The GET returns a cursor so change it to `fastify.mongo.db.collection('books').find().toArray()`
3. To get back the inserted id you need to change from <del>`inserted`</del> to `insertedId`
4. to set the MongoDB password [duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559557/how-to-enable-authentication-on-mongodb-through-docker) or you need to set the `database` property - code below updated:

- note the plugin configuration
- note the usage `fastify.mongo.db.collection`

Quick and dirty copy-paste:

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: !true })

fastify.register(require('@fastify/mongodb'), {
  forceClose: true,
  url: 'mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017',
  database: 'library'
})

fastify.get('/books', async (request, reply) => {
  const books = await fastify.mongo.db.collection('books').find().toArray()

  reply.send(books)
})

fastify.post('/books', async (request, reply) => {
  const result = await fastify
    .mongo.db
    .collection('books')
    .insertOne(request.body)

  reply.send({
    message: 'book added',
    id: result.insertedId
  })
})

async function start () {
  const done = await fastify.inject({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/books',
    body: { asd: 'foo' }
  })
  console.log(done.json())

  const res = await fastify.inject('/books')
  console.log(res.json())

  fastify.close()
}

start()
```

Comment: I have updated the answer - 3rd time I sent this comment.. SO is removing it 

Comment: Yes, ... but also I was running an old node version. Thank you for your for the support!!!